# Difference between the several ways to parallelize nested for loops in C, C++ using OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I've just started studying parallel programming with OpenMP, and there is a subtle point in the nested loop. I wrote a simple matrix multiplication code, and checked the result that is correct. But actually there are several ways to parallelize this for loop, which may be different in terms of low-level detail, and I wanna ask about it.

At first, I wrote code below, which multiply two matrix A, B and assign the result to C.

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
        for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = sum;
    }
}
```

It works, but it takes really long time. And I find out that because of the location of `parallel` directive, it will construct the parallel region N<sup>2</sup> time. I found it by huge increase in user time when I used linux time command.

Next time, I tried code below which also worked.

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, sum)
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = sum;
    }
}
```

And the elapsed time is decreased from 72.720s in sequential execution to 5.782s in parallel execution with the code above. And it is the reasonable result because I executed it with 16 cores.

But the flow of the second code is not easily drawn in my mind. I know that if we privatize all loop variables, the program will consider that nested loop as one large loop with size N<sup>3</sup>. It can be easily checked by executing the code below.

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k)
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

The `printf` was executed N<sup>3</sup> times.

But in my second matrix multiplication code, there is `sum` right before and after the innermost loop. And It bothers me to unfold the loop in my mind easily. The third code I wrote is easily unfolded in my mind.

To summarize, I want to know what really happens behind the scene in my second matrix multiplication code, especially with the change of the value of `sum`. Or I'll really thank you for some recommendation of tools to observe the flow of multithreads program written with OpenMP.

Comment: I am slightly unsure of what the question really is here. In the first case the inner-most loop is made parallel, which as, as you concluded, not the best idea. In the second, only the outer-most loop is parallelised, then each thread performs the two inner loops separately for the specific `i`. This obviously performs much better as the overhead from entering the parallel region is only "paid" once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`omp for` by default only applies to the next direct loop. The inner loops are not affected at all. This means, your can think about your second version like this:

```
// Example for two threads
with one thread execute
{
    // declare private variables "locally"
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) // loop range changed
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
            C[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}
with the other thread execute
{
    // declare private variables "locally"
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = N / 2; i < N; i++) // loop range changed
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
            C[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

You can simply all reasoning about variables with OpenMP by declaring them as locally as possible. I.e. instead of the explicit declaration use:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = sum;
    }
}
```

This way you the private scope of variable more easily.

In some cases it can be beneficial to apply parallelism to multiple loops.
This is done by using `collapse`, i.e.

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
```

You can imagine this works with a transformation like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int ij = 0; ij < N * N; ij++)
{
    int i = ij / N;
    int j = ij % N;
```

A `collapse(3)` would *not* work for this loop because of the `sum = 0` in-between.

Now is one more detail:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

is a shorthand for

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
```

The first creates the threads - the second shares the work of a loop among all threads reaching this point. This may not be of importance for the understanding now, but there are use-cases for which it matters. For instance you *could* write:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
```

I hope this sheds some light on what happens there from a logical point of view.